# why my cursor in Amcharts is "move" hover in chart ?

Tags: amcharts

Why does my cursor show this:

[image]

How do I change to default cursor?

This is my code config of amcharts for use in clone function to makeChart

```
var chartConfig =  {
           "type": "serial",
           "categoryField": "period",
           "addClassNames": true,
           "startDuration": 1,
           "categoryAxis": {
              "gridPosition": "start"
           },
           "trendLines": [],
           "graphs": [ {
              "bulletField": "last",
              "id": "", // id graph
              "lineThickness": 4,
              "title": "Redemption",
              "valueField": "total",
              "lineColor": "#ffffff",
           }],
           "chartCursor": {
              "pan": true,
              "valueLineEnabled": false,
              "valueLineBalloonEnabled": false,
              "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
              "cursorAlpha":0,
              "cursorColor":"#000000",
              "limitToGraph":"", id graph
              "valueLineAlpha":0,
              "valueZoomable":true,

           },
           "balloon": {
              "adjustBorderColor" : false,
              "borderColor": "#000000"
           },
        }
```

i delete some line because it show code mostly line and less detail .

can i fix it  ?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cursor is changed that way if you set the chartCursor's `pan` property to true. It seems like you have a very small chart in your screenshot, so you can disable the pan and set the [`zoomable`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ChartCursor#zoomable) property to false if you want a chartCursor that doesn't zoom.

```
chartCursor: {
  pan: false,
  zoomable: false,
  // other config
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/c9375ae183c090927589ff2dc24cb6b0)

Alternatively, if you need the pan functionality, you can override the cursor using css (assuming your chart div's id is chartdiv):

```
#chartdiv div { 
  cursor: default !important;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/f15aee9df03fc556ac1e7a61458fedb4)